# how to write code that assigns specific colors and line types to an edge attribute in a network with igraph in r

Tags: r, igraph

i have just recently started learning network code using the material and data by Ognyanova, found at: 
http://www.kateto.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Polnet%202015%20Network%20Viz%20Tutorial%20-%20Ognyanova.pdf

guided by some of the code in the document, I am trying to assign edge colors and then edge line types to an edge attribute, but so far unsuccessful. below is an example of the current code I tried but get many errors including this:

Error in rgb(x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19DtM.png)/255, x[2]/255, x[3]/255) : 
  color intensity NA, not in [0,1]

I have looked at many other related answered questions but unable to get the right code

```
  V(Network)$color <- colrs[V(Network)$media.type]
  ct <- colorRamp(c("black", "green"))  
E(Network)$color = sapply(ct(E(Network)$type), function(x) rgb(x[1]/255, x[2]/255, x[3]/255))    
  plot(Network, edge.arrow.size = 0.4, edge.curved = .3, vertex.label.cex = .7, vertex.label = V(Network)$media)
```

I have also tried this, but got a graph generated without edges though as shown in image below. any help will be appreciated. thanks

```
    > colrs <- c("gray50", "tomato", "gold")
```

> V(Network)$color <- colrs[V(Network)$media.type]
>     ct <- c("black", "green")
>    edge.cl <- ct[E(Network)$type]
>     plot(Network, edge.arrow.size = 0.4, edge.curved = .3, vertex.label.cex = .7, vertex.label = V(Network)$media, edge.color = edge.cl)
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19DtM.png)

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data and all necessary code. Right now we can't run your code because we don't have any of your data, and we can't see any of your output that you're trying to fix

Comment: thanks. will edit the question